# In lockstep, hand in hand, go in parallel, coincide

Tags: vocabulary

I'll give an example in which I want to use the phrases from the title:

> The company has grown in lockstep/hand in hand/in parallel with the general
>   economic growth and the development of the road networks.

or to adjust the sentence for the verb "coincide":

> The company's growth has coincided with the general economic growth
>   and the development of the road networks.

How I understand any of these words from the title, is that they do not necessarily imply a causal relationship between the company's growth and the general growth of the economy or development of its infrastructure, and I don't want to say that the company's growth was fostered by the conditions in the environment, although it is a strong implication of course. The problem is that for different reasons none of these phrases seem to be fitting my context. "In lockstep" and "hand in hand" sound to informal, and I couldn't find "in parallel" and "coincide" used in this context on Google or in language corpora. 
I was also thinking of using "follow" to say the same:

> "The expansion of the company **followed** the general growth of the
>   economy and the development of the road networks"

Comment: _In lockstep with_ definitely doesn't sound informal to me—it sounds like written language more than spoken language. If you're looking for something that's _very_ formal and non-spoken, there's always **pari passu with**. Probably the most neutral and simple solution would be the compound preposition _along with_.

Comment: "Lockstep" has a slightly negative connotation.

Comment: Thank you for the comments Janus Bahs Jacquet and Hot Licks! "The company has grown along with the general growth.." should then be fine Janus?

Comment: Paralleled and coincided could be substituted for followed in this context despite your findings. You could modify the term as loosely followed or roughly coincided.

Comment: The company’s growth ***mirrored*** the general growth of the economy...

Answer (score 2):

"In parallel with" sounds good to me. Perhaps "in concomitance with" or, with a slight change of meaning, "matching" or "keeping pace with."

Comment: Thank you for the help Conor!. Just to make sure I understand you well, the sentence sounds fine as it is with "in parallel with", and it wouldn't need to be adjusted for "matching" or "keeping pace with"?

Comment: I would keep in parallel with, yes. Jacquet's suggestion above, pari passu, is elegant but very academic.

Comment: I was looking for a neutral way of saying that, not too stiff or too loose. I understand know, thank you again for the help Conor!

Answer (score 0):

The company's growth ***reflected*** the general economic growth and the development of the road networks.

The *mirror* reference implies that the company's growth is "the same as" (a reflection of) economic growth and also receive (have reflected) the benefit of a causal relationship from both road networks and general economic growth in turn.

Comment: That's a great explanation thank you for the help Stan! I forgot to ask the previous contributors about the other choices I offered in my initial post, so if you could tell me if the other options are absolutely off the mark.

Answer (score 0):

“Coincide” works well: the events corresponded in time (and maybe more). “Correspond” works well, too. But neither especially resonates with your context, which I suspect is what you want.

Are the company’s growth, the general economy’s growth, and the development of road networks like soldiers marching with synchronized legs? Eh, not really. Are they like intimates walking together and holding hands? No, or at least it’s not a useful comparison. Are they like parallel lines? Maybe, and very much so if in fact they developed at the same rate (i.e., graph slope). Are they like reflections of each other in a mirror? Eh, sort of, if their magnitude or outline is the same.

Other possibilities include “match” (“growth matched that of the overall economy”), “accord” (“grew in accord with the overall economy”), “conform” (“performance conforming to that of the overall economy”),“jibe” (sailing) or “track” if they changed course together multiple times, or “dovetail” (woodworking) if they correspond as if by design.

The Economist contains a lot of statements like this in which authors try to add pizazz to otherwise bland discussions of causation or correspondence. I think the magazine’s style guide’s discussion of metaphors is apt, especially this quote from Orwell:

> A newly invented metaphor assists thought by evoking a visual image,
>   while on the other hand a metaphor which is technically ‘dead’ … has
>   in effect reverted to being an ordinary word and can generally be used
>   without loss of vividness. But in between these two classes there is a
>   huge dump of worn-out metaphors which are merely used because they
>   save people the trouble of inventing phrases for themselves.

http://www.economist.com/style-guide/metaphors

“Coincide” and “correspond” are non-metaphor words, at least since joining English. But many of the others still plainly involve metaphor. In particular, to my ears at least, “lockstep,” “hand in hand,” and “mirror” are in the worn-out middle ground unless they resonate cleverly with context.

I would probably just use simple words (and add color somewhere else):

> The company grew along with the overall economy as road networks developed.

But if you want to sound learned and use more abstract nouns (a benefit in some contexts, whether I like it or not), “coincide” and “correspond” work perfectly well, too:

> The company’s growth corresponded with that of the overall economy as well as with the development of road networks.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain this in detail Gregory, that is exactly what I needed to know, perfect really!